# How to avoid "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable" in BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to extract the image url from each of the products on this [page](https://www.snipes.es/c/shoes?q=jordan%2B1&openCategory=true&sz=all&srule=New), but get the following error:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "D:\Documentos\ZalandoDiscountGen-main\Zalando discout gen\scrapersnipes.py", line 98, in 
>     <module>
>     scraper()
>     File "D:\Documentos\ZalandoDiscountGen-main\Zalando discout gen\scrapersnipes.py", line 92, in 
>     scraper
>     imagen = producto.find("img", {"class": "b-dynamic_image_content b-product-tile-image ls-is-cached h- 
>     lazyloaded"})['src']
>     TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
> ```

**Code I have tried:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from dhooks import Webhook, Embed
import requests
import pandas as pd
import time, datetime
import random
import numpy as np
import os


headers = {
    'authority': 'www.snipes.es',
    'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0',
    }
'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
'accept-language': 'es-ES,es;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,de;q=0.7,eo;q=0.6',
'dnt': '1',
}


def scraper():

    response = requests.get("https://www.snipes.es/c/shoes?q=jordan%2B1&openCategory=true&sz=all&srule=New", headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    listadoproductos = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'b-product-grid-tile js-tile-container'})
    for producto in listadoproductos:
        marca = producto.find("span", {"class":"b-product-tile-brand b-product-tile-text js-product-tile-link"}).text
        titulo = producto.find("span", {"class":"b-product-tile-link js-product-tile-link"}).text
        precio = producto.find("span", {"class":"b-product-tile-price-item"}).text
        imagen = producto.find("img", {"class": "b-dynamic_image_content b-product-tile-image ls-is-cached h-lazyloaded"})['src']
        imagen2 = "https://www.snipes.es" + str(imagen)
        print (marca.strip(), titulo.strip(), precio.strip(), imagen2)
    


scraper()
```

Could not figure out what is going wrong and would be glad for a hint where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### What happens?

You try to find the `<img>` with multiple classes, what would not work this way and is not necessary.

Think you also wont have the `src`cause it is an blank png, what you might want is the `data-src`

### How to fix that?

Change your line, where you try to find the image to the following:

```
imagen = producto.select_one('div.b-product-tile-image-container img')['data-src']
```

And also skip the imagen2, you wont need it:

```
for producto in listadoproductos:
    marca = producto.find("span", {"class":"b-product-tile-brand b-product-tile-text js-product-tile-link"}).text
    titulo = producto.find("span", {"class":"b-product-tile-link js-product-tile-link"}).text
    precio = producto.find("span", {"class":"b-product-tile-price-item"}).text
    imagen = producto.select_one('div.b-product-tile-image-container img')['data-src']
    print (marca.strip(), titulo.strip(), precio.strip(), imagen)
```

**Output**

> JORDAN WMNS Zoom '92 149,99 €
> https://www.snipes.es/dw/image/v2/BDCB_PRD/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-snse-master-eu/default/dw1986ce4d/1899597_P.jpg?sw=300&sh=300&sm=fit&sfrm=png
> JORDAN Air Jordan 1 Mid (PS) 64,99 €
> https://www.snipes.es/dw/image/v2/BDCB_PRD/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-snse-master-eu/default/dwe2e88c0b/1930682_P.jpg?sw=300&sh=300&sm=fit&sfrm=png
> JORDAN Air Jordan 11 Crib Bootie 59,99 €
> https://www.snipes.es/dw/image/v2/BDCB_PRD/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-snse-master-eu/default/dw2dd01aa4/1883653_P.jpg?sw=300&sh=300&sm=fit&sfrm=png
> JORDAN Jordan Air Max 200 129,99 €
> https://www.snipes.es/dw/image/v2/BDCB_PRD/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-snse-master-eu/default/dw21a7bda8/1829411_P.jpg?sw=300&sh=300&sm=fit&sfrm=png

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I have been with this problem for a long time and did not know the use of select_one